# Will Application_Start also be triggered on page update?

Tags: asp.net

If I upload a new version of my site to my live server by using FTP and the "Replace existing files" option, will the "Application_Start" event in my Global.asax file be triggered once its uploaded?

If not, when does it trigger? Do I have to restart the server after an upload to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be triggered on the first request to any application's resource. You don't need to restart the server as application will be restarted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are uploading an aspx page, in that case `Application_Start` won't fire.

The simplest way to restart the app in such situation would be to 'touch' the web.config file.